1990s cartoon regarding three heroes
There used to be a show on Cartoon Network on late 1990s - where there used to be three super heroes. At the time of any war, one used to handle battle on earth wearing a yellow suit. One used to handle sea wearing a green suit and one used to handle space wearing a blue suit.
That's what I can remember now. What is the name of the show? This show has been hovering on my head for the last few days, and I need to see several of the episodes... 

@Downvoter, please care to explain. The question was valid, the answer was accepted and valid THEN WHY downvote?

I think you're looking for The Centurions 1986
The characters seem to fit your description.
Original Team:
Max Ray - 'Brilliant' Sea Operations Commander: The calm and collected de facto leader of the team, donning a green power suit and sporting a fine moustache . His weapon systems are best suited for underwater missions.
Jake Rockwell - 'Rugged' Land Operations Specialist: Donning a yellow power suit, he has a short fuse. His weapon systems have the most firepower and are best suited for land missions, except for a helicopter-themed system he uses in air combat, usually assisted by Ace.
Ace McCloud - 'Daring' Air Operations Expert: Donning a blue power suit, he is a brave but cocky womanizer who is sometimes at odds with Jake. His weapon systems are best suited for aerial missions, including one specially designed for battles in space.

Sir, I wish you live a long happy life! Thanks...

My childhood is suddenly revisited +1
